# <div> width is shrinking when using inline-flex and messing with another element

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to display `div`s and `span`s on the same line and I want the divs to fill all available width. However, when I use `display: inline-flex`, the `div` widths shrink to ~= 30% of the available free space.

```css
 

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif
}

.list-item {
    cursor: auto;
    display: inline-flex;
    margin-top: 11px;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #5c636a;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background-color: #212529;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.example-group {
    display: block;
}

body {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
 

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
    <div class="example-group">
        <span>
            <svg height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" width="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="white">
                <path
                    d="M8.5 4c0 .82843-.67157 1.5-1.5 1.5S5.5 4.82843 5.5 4 6.17157 2.5 7 2.5s1.5.67157 1.5 1.5zM7 11.5c.82843 0 1.5-.6716 1.5-1.5 0-.82843-.67157-1.5-1.5-1.5s-1.5.67157-1.5 1.5c0 .8284.67157 1.5 1.5 1.5zm0 6c.82843 0 1.5-.6716 1.5-1.5s-.67157-1.5-1.5-1.5-1.5.6716-1.5 1.5.67157 1.5 1.5 1.5zm6 0c.8284 0 1.5-.6716 1.5-1.5s-.6716-1.5-1.5-1.5-1.5.6716-1.5 1.5.6716 1.5 1.5 1.5zm1.5-7.5c0 .8284-.6716 1.5-1.5 1.5s-1.5-.6716-1.5-1.5c0-.82843.6716-1.5 1.5-1.5s1.5.67157 1.5 1.5zM13 5.5c.8284 0 1.5-.67157 1.5-1.5s-.6716-1.5-1.5-1.5-1.5.67157-1.5 1.5.6716 1.5 1.5 1.5z"></path>
            </svg>
        </span>
        <div class="list-item">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="example-group">
        <span>
            <svg height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" width="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="white">
                <path
                    d="M8.5 4c0 .82843-.67157 1.5-1.5 1.5S5.5 4.82843 5.5 4 6.17157 2.5 7 2.5s1.5.67157 1.5 1.5zM7 11.5c.82843 0 1.5-.6716 1.5-1.5 0-.82843-.67157-1.5-1.5-1.5s-1.5.67157-1.5 1.5c0 .8284.67157 1.5 1.5 1.5zm0 6c.82843 0 1.5-.6716 1.5-1.5s-.67157-1.5-1.5-1.5-1.5.6716-1.5 1.5.67157 1.5 1.5 1.5zm6 0c.8284 0 1.5-.6716 1.5-1.5s-.6716-1.5-1.5-1.5-1.5.6716-1.5 1.5.6716 1.5 1.5 1.5zm1.5-7.5c0 .8284-.6716 1.5-1.5 1.5s-1.5-.6716-1.5-1.5c0-.82843.6716-1.5 1.5-1.5s1.5.67157 1.5 1.5zM13 5.5c.8284 0 1.5-.67157 1.5-1.5s-.6716-1.5-1.5-1.5-1.5.67157-1.5 1.5.6716 1.5 1.5 1.5z"></path>
            </svg>
        </span>
        <div class="list-item">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="example-group">
        <span>
            <svg height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" width="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="white">
                <path
                    d="M8.5 4c0 .82843-.67157 1.5-1.5 1.5S5.5 4.82843 5.5 4 6.17157 2.5 7 2.5s1.5.67157 1.5 1.5zM7 11.5c.82843 0 1.5-.6716 1.5-1.5 0-.82843-.67157-1.5-1.5-1.5s-1.5.67157-1.5 1.5c0 .8284.67157 1.5 1.5 1.5zm0 6c.82843 0 1.5-.6716 1.5-1.5s-.67157-1.5-1.5-1.5-1.5.6716-1.5 1.5.67157 1.5 1.5 1.5zm6 0c.8284 0 1.5-.6716 1.5-1.5s-.6716-1.5-1.5-1.5-1.5.6716-1.5 1.5.6716 1.5 1.5 1.5zm1.5-7.5c0 .8284-.6716 1.5-1.5 1.5s-1.5-.6716-1.5-1.5c0-.82843.6716-1.5 1.5-1.5s1.5.67157 1.5 1.5zM13 5.5c.8284 0 1.5-.67157 1.5-1.5s-.6716-1.5-1.5-1.5-1.5.67157-1.5 1.5.6716 1.5 1.5 1.5z"></path>
            </svg>
        </span>
        <div class="list-item">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If `display: inline-flex` is removed from `list-item`, the desired effect happens but the `div`s and `span`s are no longer on the same line. I want both on the same line and all the available space filled by the `div`s

[image: effect]

Comment: Hi. Check my answer, I hope it helps you :)

Comment: I did, thanks it's very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term 'flex' refers to the container, not the item. You need to set `display:flex` to the `.example-group` container then force the `.list-item` div to grow by applying `flex-grow:1` to that.  Marked up code below.

[CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) has a great cheatsheet for flex and Kevin Powell also does a good introductory [video](https://youtu.be/u044iM9xsWU)

**Edited** `align-items:center` added to put the svg in the center.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.list-item {
  cursor: auto;
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-top: 11px;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #5c636a;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background-color: #212529;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.example-group {
  display: flex; /*added this */
  align-items:center; /*added this */
  background-color:gray; /* set this so you can see the SVG */
}

/* added this */
.list-item {
  flex-grow:1;
}

body {
  background-color: #1a1e21;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <div class="example-group">
    <span>
      <svg height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" width="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="white">
        <path d="M8.5 4c0 .82843-.67157 1.5-1.5 1.5S5.5 4.82843 5.5 4 6.17157 2.5 7 2.5s1.5.67157 1.5 1.5zM7 11.5c.82843 0 1.5-.6716 1.5-1.5 0-.82843-.67157-1.5-1.5-1.5s-1.5.67157-1.5 1.5c0 .8284.67157 1.5 1.5 1.5zm0 6c.82843 0 1.5-.6716 1.5-1.5s-.67157-1.5-1.5-1.5-1.5.6716-1.5 1.5.67157 1.5 1.5 1.5zm6 0c.8284 0 1.5-.6716 1.5-1.5s-.6716-1.5-1.5-1.5-1.5.6716-1.5 1.5.6716 1.5 1.5 1.5zm1.5-7.5c0 .8284-.6716 1.5-1.5 1.5s-1.5-.6716-1.5-1.5c0-.82843.6716-1.5 1.5-1.5s1.5.67157 1.5 1.5zM13 5.5c.8284 0 1.5-.67157 1.5-1.5s-.6716-1.5-1.5-1.5-1.5.67157-1.5 1.5.6716 1.5 1.5 1.5z"></path>
      </svg>
    </span>
    <div class="list-item">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="example-group">
    <span>
      <svg height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" width="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="white">
        <path d="M8.5 4c0 .82843-.67157 1.5-1.5 1.5S5.5 4.82843 5.5 4 6.17157 2.5 7 2.5s1.5.67157 1.5 1.5zM7 11.5c.82843 0 1.5-.6716 1.5-1.5 0-.82843-.67157-1.5-1.5-1.5s-1.5.67157-1.5 1.5c0 .8284.67157 1.5 1.5 1.5zm0 6c.82843 0 1.5-.6716 1.5-1.5s-.67157-1.5-1.5-1.5-1.5.6716-1.5 1.5.67157 1.5 1.5 1.5zm6 0c.8284 0 1.5-.6716 1.5-1.5s-.6716-1.5-1.5-1.5-1.5.6716-1.5 1.5.6716 1.5 1.5 1.5zm1.5-7.5c0 .8284-.6716 1.5-1.5 1.5s-1.5-.6716-1.5-1.5c0-.82843.6716-1.5 1.5-1.5s1.5.67157 1.5 1.5zM13 5.5c.8284 0 1.5-.67157 1.5-1.5s-.6716-1.5-1.5-1.5-1.5.67157-1.5 1.5.6716 1.5 1.5 1.5z"></path>
      </svg>
    </span>
    <div class="list-item">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="example-group">
    <span>
      <svg height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" width="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="white">
        <path d="M8.5 4c0 .82843-.67157 1.5-1.5 1.5S5.5 4.82843 5.5 4 6.17157 2.5 7 2.5s1.5.67157 1.5 1.5zM7 11.5c.82843 0 1.5-.6716 1.5-1.5 0-.82843-.67157-1.5-1.5-1.5s-1.5.67157-1.5 1.5c0 .8284.67157 1.5 1.5 1.5zm0 6c.82843 0 1.5-.6716 1.5-1.5s-.67157-1.5-1.5-1.5-1.5.6716-1.5 1.5.67157 1.5 1.5 1.5zm6 0c.8284 0 1.5-.6716 1.5-1.5s-.6716-1.5-1.5-1.5-1.5.6716-1.5 1.5.6716 1.5 1.5 1.5zm1.5-7.5c0 .8284-.6716 1.5-1.5 1.5s-1.5-.6716-1.5-1.5c0-.82843.6716-1.5 1.5-1.5s1.5.67157 1.5 1.5zM13 5.5c.8284 0 1.5-.67157 1.5-1.5s-.6716-1.5-1.5-1.5-1.5.67157-1.5 1.5.6716 1.5 1.5 1.5z"></path>
      </svg>
    </span>
    <div class="list-item">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For some reason, this causes `<span>` elements to float to the top

Comment: That can be fixed by setting the 'align-items' property in the .example-group rule to center. I'll update my answer to show this

Comment: is there a better way to vertically center the svgs?

Comment: For flexbox the align-items propoerty is pretty much the way to go.  Does it not align up exactly as you intended?

Comment: It aligns the items in the same way they were aligned in the question's snippet. However, I still don't like how they look which is a separate issue.

Comment: I've noticed that the SVGs don't align with the baseline of the .list item text. That's because you've added an 11px margin-top to the .list-item.  You could possibly change that so that you add a margin top and bottom to that item. Or use the flexbox gap property in the parent of the example-group div.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood well, you only need to do this:

```
.example-group {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.list-item {
  width: 100%;
}
```

In order to make it look better centered you can also do this:

- Remove the margin-top in `.list-item`
- And add the following to the div that wraps all the `.example-group` divs:

  `display: flex; flex-direction: column; gap: 11px;`

The result is:

[image]

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I included `margin-top` to seal the gaps between the `.list-item` elements and to have the same margin at the very top, so unless there's another more simple way to achieve the same thing, I think using `margin-top`  would be better in this case.

Comment: If you do what I say in the second point you don't need to use the margin to add that gap. Just add `display: flex; flex-direction: column; gap: 11px;` to the div that wraps all the .example-group elements. In addition you can add `padding-top: 11px;` to the same div in order to add that gap also at the very top